# boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++, boost, callback, ros

I am creating a ROS subscriber and trying to use it's data from callback function. I followed the [[ROS Q&A] 187 - Unable to use data received in callback function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JgubTDa7kk&t=771s). I am getting the following error

```
listener: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:734: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Code

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"



class Listener
{
public:
  std_msgs::String::ConstPtr data; //attribute
  void callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg);
};
// %EndTag(CLASS_WITH_DECLARATION)%

void Listener::callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) 
{ 
  data = msg; 
  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ Listener listener;
  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener_class");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

// %Tag(SUBSCRIBER)%
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &Listener::callback, &listener);

// %EndTag(SUBSCRIBER)%
  
  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
  while(ros::ok())
  {
  std::cout << " Data is " << listener.data->data.c_str() << std::endl;
  ros::spinOnce();
  loop_rate.sleep();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand the problem is because of this line `std_msgs::String::ConstPtr data` as when the subscriber starts it don't get any message for few milliseconds and it's complanning it's empty in a c++ way.

One solution is to remove ConstPtr but by passing a const pointer into the callback, we avoid doing a copy.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be storing a ROS callback message as a `String::ConstPointer`, you should be storing the message data directly. Such as:

```
class Listener
{
  public:
    std::string data; //attribute
    void callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg);
};

void Listener::callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) 
{ 
  data = msg->data; 
}
```

After the callback return the message and pointer will be deconstructed

Comment: I tried using your suggestion but I am getting the follwoing error 




```required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2378:11: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&>’
 2378 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
```